# Using getopt for obtaining non-specified arguments C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm writing a program which needs to be able to parse command line arguments, and I would like to use getopt. I have no issues with getting it to work with the regular arguments, however I need it to be able to pick up an argument that is not specified with a flag. For example if I ran: `./prog -a a1 -b b2 foo` I would need to be able to get a1,a2 and foo. Right now it handles everything but the unspecified argument. Here is what I have:

```
while((command = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:c:")) != -1){
        switch(command){
            case('a'):
                input = fopen(optarg, "r");
                if(input == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening file, exiting\n");
                    exit( -1 );
                }
                break;

            case('b'):
                output = fopen(optarg, "r");
                if(output == NULL){
                    printf("Error opening file, exiting\n");
                    exit( -1 );
                }
                break;

            case('c'):
                keyword = optarg;
                break;


            case('?'):
                if((optopt == 'a') || (optopt == 'b') || (optopt == 'c')){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error, no argument specified for -%c\n", optopt);
                    exit( -1 );
                } else
                    extra = optarg; // This is how I thought I needed to do it

                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr,"Error in getopt");
                break;
        }// switch
    } // while
```

Thanks!

Comment: I jsut read "All is working fine, here is my code: [...]" whats your problem?

Comment: It handles everything but the unspecified argument. As in, if the user inputs an argument without a flag (a,b,c) my code is not handling it.

Comment: Ah, well... Then you disadvantageous phrased your OP. But ok, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the loop, the `optind` variable will be the index to the next non-option argument.

So do e.g.

```
if (optind < argc)
{
    printf("Have extra arguments: ");
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

to list all non-option arguments.